# I would like to convert an instance of object to an instance of a type known only at runtime

Tags: c#

Something that would work like this:

```
object myObjet = GetObject();
Type myType = GetType();

var x = ConvertToType(myObject, myType);
```

myobject could be a primitive or something else. If the conversion is impossible than an exception is thrown. Is there something built-in in the framework. The System.Convert class require you to know the destination type.

Comment: Would this work? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.changetype?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: Do you want `x` to be statically typed?

Comment: If such a method existed, how and why would you use it? My first reaction is to explain why we shouldn't do this, but that means I'm making assumptions. I suspect that writing and using this method will lead to complicated code both when the method is called and when you try to use the result you get back, because it means that everything is declared as `object` and the code isn't type safe. The method itself is the simplest part. It's a bunch of "if myobject is this type and mytype is that type, do this conversion and return it." If none of those are met, the last line throws an exception.

Answer (score 0):

You could write exactly the method you'r describing. It might look like this:

```
object ConvertToType(object source, Type targetType)
{
    var sourceType = source.GetType();

    if (sourceType == typeof(Something) && targetType == typeof(SomethingElse))
    {
        // call some function that takes the input and converts it to the output type.
        return ConvertSomethingToSomethingElse((Something) source);
    }

    // Repeat the above, over and over. Every time there's a new type conversion, 
    // add it.

    throw new Exception($"Can't convert {sourceType} to {targetType}");
}
```

That could get ugly if there are lots of possible conversions. (Is there a perfect number of conversions where this method makes sense? I'd lean towards no, but that's an opinion.)

You could use [Automapper](https://automapper.org/). Your method would look like this:

```
object ConvertToType<T>(object source, Type targetType)
{
    return Mapper.Map(source, source.GetType(), targetType);
}
```

You'd still have to configure all the mappings and in some cases write functions to perform every possible combination of conversions you want to support. There's no getting around that.

What both approaches illustrate is that while the answer is, "Yes, you can do that," there's no free lunch. No matter how you slice it you still have to write code to handle all of the conversions. If you're already doing all of that, does having all of that pass through a single method make sense? There may be scenarios (or else that `Map` overload wouldn't even exist) but in most cases I doubt that it's helpful.

It's not a pattern I'd generally recommend because it implies code that isn't type safe will call this method, and the result is an `object` which isn't type-safe either. If at all possible, since you still have to write type-safe code to do the conversions, I'd just use those methods directly instead of using `object`.